# Rancher in Docker doesn't create snapshot data to host

Tags: docker, centos, vps, docker-volume, rancher

I am running Rancher 1.6 in Docker on VPS with CentOS 7. I would like to share configuration data with host (don't loose data if docker container failed).

Before starting rancher container, I create folder on host:

```
HOST_VOLUME=$HOME/rancher-data/mysql
mkdir -p $HOST_VOLUME
```

Then start rancher server:

```
sudo docker run -d \
-v $HOST_VOLUME:/var/lib/mysql \
--restart=unless-stopped \
-p 8080:8080 \
rancher/server
```

I setup Rancher - authentication, added couple of hosts and containers which are now running. But the folder on host ($HOME/rancher-data/mysql) is empty. If I switch inside container with cmd, I can see in /var/lib/mysql a lot of files which Rancher is using, but they are not mirrored to host.

Comment: Might be a silly thing to do, but can you directly give a whole volume name with absolute path instead of having a variable volume name and see if it's same or different

Comment: Rancher 1.6 is several years old and only receives maintenance updates. Rancher 2.x has been out since 2018. Rancher 2.4.4 was released today. 

Are you running 1.6 for a reason? Can you switch over to 2.4 instead?

Comment: I read somewhere that Rancher 2.x requires Kubernetes, so it is the reason why I choose 1.x.

Comment: That's correct. Rancher 2.x is based entirely on Kubernetes. I would encourage you to learn Kubernetes - it's the best path to a guaranteed future income in IT where containers are concerned.

If you would rather not learn Kubernetes, I'd encourage you to use something other than Rancher 1.6, not because there's anything wrong with Rancher 1.6 (I work for Rancher), but because 1.6 is not under active development. Go with Swarm or ECS or something else, but only if Kubernetes is completely out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this out on an Ubuntu system, and I'm not able to duplicate what you're experiencing. My thought was that this was related to sudo not passing the environment from your local use to root due to `env_reset` in `/etc/sudoers`, but I removed that from my `sudoers` file and it still worked fine.

To further test this on your system, I would do the following:

1. If there's a problem, it's with Docker, not with Rancher, so test it with `busybox` instead of the `rancher/rancher` container. Run the same command like this: `sudo docker run -it --rm -v $HOST_VOLUME:/var/lib/mysql busybox ash`. This will drop you into a shell in the container - use `df -h` to see if the volume from your host is mounted on `/var/lib/mysql` in the container. If so, then the command itself is working, and we just need to find out *where* that mount is.
2. From another login to the same system (while the above container is running), look at it with `docker inspect <container_id>` and look for the HostConfig section. You should see your volume mount under `Binds`.

```
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "/home/ubuntu/test:/test"
    ],
```

3. If you don't see it there, then Docker is ignoring your request to mount that. Try it again with an absolute path, as @nischay-goyal suggested. You can also look in the system log for error output about why Docker won't mount a volume as requested. I would expect it to error out and fail, but maybe there's something else acting as a noop and it's continuing anyway. Logs will give you more information.
4. If nothing above works, rule out the "dual user environment" issue that sudo is bringing by adding your local user to the `docker` group. Log out and back in. Re-run your `docker run` command without `sudo` and see if it works as expected.